# Error in import import net.proteanit.sql.DbUtils package in netbean ID 7.0RC2

Tags: java, database, netbeans, netbeans-7

[image: Error in import of net.proteanit.sql.DbUtils package]

I don't know to solve this problem does i need to add external jar please mention the name of jar to use this package.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need the JAR file rs2xml.jar to resolve this problem.